# How can I determine the amount of nested functions and I can use before I get a StackLevel Error?

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm reading Sandi Metz's book on Object Oriented Design and one of her main principles is the idea of single responsibility. Below is a example from her book where she refactors code to illustrate that point.

```
def gear_inches
  foo = some_intermediate_result * wheel.diameter
end
```

---

```
def gear_inches
  foo = some_intermediate_result * diameter
end

def diameter
  wheel.diameter
end
```

With this refactoring, how can I determine up to what point I can refactor a method with single responsibility until I get a Stack Level error? For example

```
def gear_inches
  foo = some_intermediate_result * diameter
end

def diameter
  wheel.diameter * calculation
end

def calculation
  wheel.calculation * another_calculation
end

def another_calculation
  wheel.another_calculation * yet_another_calculation
end

def yet_another_calculation
  wheel.yet_another_calculation
end
```

and so on and so forth. How can I determine the level of nested functions without abusing the Single Responsibility design?

Comment: You're not going to reach a stackLevelTooDeep this way. Not without some sort of recursion/circular logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show you the number of nested calls that result in a stack overflow for one particular example:

```
def my_function a
  my_function(a + 1)
rescue Exception => e
  puts "a is #{a}"
  puts e.message
end

my_function(1)
```

Results in:

```
a is 8732
stack level too deep
```

So, a stack overflow resulted after 8,732 calls.

The actual number of nested calls that will result in a stack overflow depend on a number of factors (e.g. arguments passed, etc.), but in general, I don't think you need to worry about the stack level when manually creating the nested calls. A stack overflow usually results from a recursive call.